# The R Book example matrix and aggregate()

Tags: r

Good evening,

I am using "The R Book" by Michael J. Crawley.  I understand that it is not the best book for learning R... But that what I have.

So in chapter 2 he explain calculations on rows and columns. So out of this came that question.

Here is a series of command in R (R-studio) and I have a simple question to ask.

```
X <- matrix(rpois(20, 1.5), nrow=4)
X

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    2    2    0    0    2
#[2,]    2    1    0    0    2
#[3,]    1    0    1    2    0
#[4,]    2    1    2    0    2

group = c("A", "B", "B", "A")
aggregate(X, list(group), sum)

#          **************
#  Group.1 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1       A  4  3  2  0  4
#2       B  3  1  1  2  2
```

The question is how did the column titles (*) did appeared ...

V1 is probably Vector 1, V2 Vector 2 ...

Is that intrinsic to the function aggregate()?

Cheers

Claude

Comment: I don't know if it's the same in 2nd ed but in the first ed the page between the construction of that matrix and the example using aggregate had an assignment of a vector to the colnames(X) and the columns would have been labeled with those. (And then Crawley showed the results with "V"n's, as if that code had not been run.)

Comment: Thelatemail Thanks for the editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?aggregate`:

"*The default method... coerces ‘x’ to a data frame and calls the data frame method.*"

`as.data.frame(X)` gives you the `Vn` column names:

```
as.data.frame(X)

#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  0  1  1  0  2
#2  1  3  2  1  1
#3  1  3  2  0  0
#4  3  2  2  1  1
```